# Complex update query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table 1**

```
|id|name|address|car_id  |
|1 |Alex|US     |NULL    |
|2 |Jaso|Canada |1       |
```

**Table 2**

```
|car_id|color|
|1     |red  |
|2     |blue |
```

I am trying to update Alex's car_id with the car_id of the blue car in the second table. Is it possible to do it in one query?

I tried writing the query below, but couldn't make it work. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE table1
   SET table1.car_id = table2.car_id
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2 
    ON table2.color = "blue"
 WHERE table1.name = "Alex"
```

**Desired result:**

```
|id|name|address|car_id  |
|1 |Alex|US     |2       |
|2 |Jaso|Canada |1       |
```

Comment: `UPDATE t1
      JOIN t2
        ON t2.color = 'blue'
       SET t1.car_id = t2.car_id
     WHERE t1.car_id IS NULL;`

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hqisnGMouLofGMmbPn2LjK/0)

Comment: Yes, Strawberry's solution worked! Thank you!

Comment: You should post it as an answer so I can pick it to be the answer!

Comment: It's too trivial

Comment: Your query looks like it would be suitable for sql server - mysql syntax is different read up on Multiple-table syntax:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it does not work in one query. [Edit: Wrong, see other answer]

You have 2 different requirements for 2 different tables which do not have a common column.
You need to find the blue car_id independently from Alexes row as they are not linked in any way by now.

I would do it as follows:

```
UPDATE
  table1
SET
  table.car_id = (
    SELECT
      car_id
    FROM
      table2
    WHERE
      color LIKE 'blue'
  )
WHERE
  name LIKE 'Alex'
```

Comment: I suspect you're mistaken

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the oneliner solution is more complicated than nessesary with no performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

update firstTable join secondTable on secondTable.color = 'blue' set firstTable.car_id = secondTable.car_id where firstTable.car_id is null;

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for a similar problem with more people and more cars.
Maybe it helps [DBfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2bc38a77a1d30216e62e1eaa657dc255)

The base datatabke are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `address` varchar(7), `car_id` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
(`id`, `name`, `address`, `car_id`)
VALUES
(1, 'Alex', 'US', NULL),
(2, 'Jaso', 'Canad a', '1'),
(3, 'Paso', 'Canad a', NULL),
(4, 'Paso', 'danad a', NULL)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
(`car_id` int, `color` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
(`car_id`, `color`)
VALUES
(1, 'red'),
(2, 'blue'),
(3, 'green') ,
(4, 'purple')
;
```

The sql statement for mysql till 5.7

```
Update Table1 t1a inner Join
(Select tab1.id, tab2.car_id From
( Select 
   `id`,
   @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
  FROM Table1, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
  WHERE car_id IS NULL ) tab1 
inner join
( Select 
    car_id,
    @curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank
  From Table2 , (SELECT @curRank2 := 0) r Where car_id NOT IN 
   (
    Select Car_id From
      (Select GROUP_CONCAT(t1.car_id) car_id FROM Table1 as t1) t1e 
       WHERE car_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY car_id

      ) 
  ) tab2 
  ON   tab1.rank = tab2.rank) t2a
on t1a.id = t2a.id
SET t1a.car_id = t2a.car_ID
;
```

The Problem that we face here is that we need actually the car_ids from table taht are already taken. And then select only rest of the car_id, that are not selected yet.
After that we have to make the statement so that ver person gets one color ann that every colour is selected only once. that takes a little code because we have no relationship betwenn tabel1 car_ids thta are NULL and table2.

So result is

```
id  name    address     car_id
 1  Alex    US          2
 2  Jaso    Canad a     1
 3  Paso    Canad a     3
 4  Paso    danad a     4
```

With mysql 8 you use window function instead of the vehicle rank.